# train_test_split producing inconsistent samples

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am working on using `sklearn`'s `train_test_split` to create a training set and testing set of my data.

My script is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import neighbors
# function to perform one hot encoding and dropping the original item
# in this case its the part number
def encode_and_bind(original_dataframe, feature_to_encode):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(original_dataframe[[feature_to_encode]])
    res = pd.concat([original_dataframe, dummies], axis=1)
    res = res.drop([feature_to_encode], axis=1)
    return(res)

# read in data from csv
data = pd.read_csv('export2.csv')

# one hot encode the part number
new = encode_and_bind(data, 'PART_NO')

# create the labels, or field we are trying to estimate
label = new['TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE']
# remove the header
label = label[1:]

# create the data, or the data that is to be estimated
thedata = new.drop('TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE', axis=1)
# remove the header
thedata = thedata[1:]

print(label.shape)
print(thedata.shape)

# # split into training and testing sets
train_data, train_classes, test_data, test_classes = train_test_split(thedata, label, test_size = 0.3)

# create a knn model
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor()
# fit it with our data
knn.fit(train_data, train_classes)
```

Running it, I get the following:

> C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py (6262,) (6262, 253) Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 37, in 
>       knn.fit(train_data, train_classes)   File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line
>   872, in fit
>       X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)   File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line
>   729, in check_X_y
>       check_consistent_length(X, y)   File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line
>   205, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4383, 1879]

So, it looks like both my `X` and `Y` have the same number of rows (6262), but different # of columns, since I thought `Y` was just supposed to be one column of the label or value you are trying to predict.

How can I use `train_test_split` to give me a training and testing dataset that I can use for a KNN Regressor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've switched the outputs of `train_test_split`, from what I can tell.

The function returns, in order: Training features, Testing features, Training labels, Testing labels.

The common naming convention is `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=...` where `X` is the features (columns or features) and `y`y is the targets (labels or, I'm assuming, "classes" in your code)

You appear to be trying to get it to return, instead, `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test`

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
train_data, test_data, train_classes, test_classes = train_test_split(thedata, label, test_size = 0.3)
```